# Which tag(s) should be used for Intel FPGAs?

Tags: discussion, tags

Since Altera was acquired by Intel in 2015, Altera brand was withdrew. The company (Altera) completely became a part of Intel and all social media accounts were renamed "Intel FPGA". <sup>[1](https://twitter.com/intelfpga),[2](https://www.linkedin.com/showcase/intelfpga/),[3](https://www.facebook.com/IntelFPGA/)</sup>

Should we create [intel-fpga](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intel-fpga) tag to use instead of [altera](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/altera), or should we add [intel](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intel) and [fpga](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fpga) tags to the (new) questions?

Comment: Done - the intel-fpga tag is now in effect.

Comment: @W5VO Thanks very much.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It does seem like Intel and Altera are getting close to finalizing the acquisition. The www.altera.com website warns it will be redirected to intel.com on 6/30/2018.

Here's my proposed set of actions:

- Create the tag [intel-fpga](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intel-fpga)
- Replace [altera](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/altera) with [intel-fpga](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intel-fpga)
- Make [altera](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/altera) a synonym of [intel-fpga](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intel-fpga)

---

My rationale is that the [altera](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/altera) tag is a good filter for FPGA/CLPD questions, and [intel](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intel) focuses on x86/x64 type offerings. There is also a good argument for merging [altera](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/altera) into [intel](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intel), or making [altera](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/altera) a synonym for [intel](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intel). If someone feels strongly for either of those alternatives (or even doing nothing), please post an answer suggesting that.

Comment: Your proposal seems the best option to me as well.

Comment: Add family name too: Stratix, Cyclone, etc.  These usually don't change during an acquisition.

Comment: Makes sense to create [intel-fpga] and adding the synonym for [altera]. Quartus has been Intel branded for a good 2 years now. I would be against changing [altera] to just [intel].

Comment: Agreed, `altera` and `intel-fpga` synonym as colloquially, "Altera" will be used for some time going forward... at least, until the millennials take over :(

Comment: @CapnJJ Clearly the millennials are all responsible for the fall of great company names of old.

Comment: Altera/Intel also  make CPLDs. Maybe the tag should be `intel-programmable-logic` or `intel-pld` instead of `intel-fpga`.

Comment: @ThePhoton Intel introduces the whole PL department as "Intel FPGA" (e.g. the logo on altera.com). I think, it is better to follow the official use.